# Is callFromThread threadsafe

Tags: thread-safety, twisted

I looked at the code for callFromThread. It's appending all the callables into threadCallQueue list. If multiple threads call callFromThread, how can callFromThread be thread-safe? In other words, without a lock on threadCallQueue, how can callFromThread be threadsafe? Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple threads can add items to the list (these are the producers) and it's always done through an *append()* call (so, at the end of the list):

```
self.threadCallQueue.append((f, args, kw))
```

Only the main thread ever reads items and removes them from the list (this one is the consumer) and it always reads at the beginning of the list:

```
# Keep track of how many calls we actually make, as we're
# making them, in case another call is added to the queue
# while we're in this loop.
count = 0
total = len(self.threadCallQueue)
for (f, a, kw) in self.threadCallQueue:
    try:
        f(*a, **kw)
    except:
        log.err()
    count += 1
    if count == total:
        break
del self.threadCallQueue[:count]
```

So, since one thread reads from the beginning of the list and others write at the end, this is thread-safe **as long as Python lists are**. This is noted in the function's source code:

```
# lists are thread-safe in CPython, but not in Jython
# this is probably a bug in Jython, but until fixed this code
# won't work in Jython.
```